# How is my app starting on boot? (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

I am not very Linux literate. I have a node app that I installed a couple of years ago on a server. I can't remember how I set it up to start on boot. If I execute

```
ls /etc/init.d
```

I don't see anything related to my application. There must be a script somewhere that has the commands

```
cd /opt/siteServer
node app.js
```

Comment: Have you tried grepping for the script name? If you’re lucky and the startup logic is actually in clear text, `grep -r 'app.js' / 2>/dev/null` should list the file that starts your app. If not, you could use `pstree` to find the parent command that launched your app.

Comment: Did you set it as a service with `systemctl`?